# How to prevent img from being loaded when it does not exist

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm using this jquery snippet to create an image swap on hover based on the name of the excisting image (adding -hover at the end).

The only problem is that when the hover version of the image does not exist it will give a 404 error. I added a line of code that adds display: none to the none existing images.

I was wondering if there is a way to prevent the img from being appended when the src does not exist. Here is the code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(window).load(function() {
    var foto_container = $(".et_pb_image .et_pb_image_wrap");
    foto_container.each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).find('.et_overlay').length) {
            var str = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
            var strNew = str.replace(".jpg", "-hover.jpg");
            $(this).append('<div class="image_hover_wrapper"><img class="image_hover" src="' + strNew + '"></div>');
            $(this).find('.image_hover').on('error', function(){
                $(this).css("display", 'none');
            });
        }
    });
});
});
```

I'm a jquery beginner so sorry if this code makes you cry hehe. I hope this is enough information!

Comment: No, you can't tell if the image doesn't exist before you attempt to load it. You can hook an event handler to the `error` event on the `img` to hide the image if it fails to load, but you'll still see the 404 error in the console.

Comment: Alright, good to know. Thanks!